# Android Studio stuck at launcher after latest patch update

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Android Studio is stuck at launcher after latest patch update. I got the patch update on latest Bumblebee and it is now stuck at the launcher only.

Attached screenshot for reference. What should I do now?

Note: I had installed CSV support plugins and also this patch updated. Both were installed and restarted.

[image]

Comment: "I might have some unsaved changes" - in Android Studio itself?!

Comment: Can you help me with the solution instead of finding the mistakes? @snachmsm

Comment: I would just re-install AS

Comment: I tried reinstall. Even then it's the same thing. It gets stuck at the same place. @snachmsm